# Trying to feed two buildings on a property with one Incoming cable service

Tags: coaxial-cable

I have a property with a main house and also a guest house.  I am experiencing some iffy quality cable TV quality and I believe it is because of the way I am splitting the signal at the guest house.

- The incoming comcast coax goes into a comscope, powered amplifier.
- Out of that amplifier, one cable goes about 70ft to a Tivo box that powers the TV's in that house.  No issues with the quality on the TV's that use that signal.
- A second cable going out of the comscope goes 270ft to the guest house.  In this house, I feed a cable internet modem which is 5ft away from the splitters in this house.  a second feed goes to another TIVO box which is 5ft away.  A third feed goes 50' to a third TIVO box.

I currently don't have any splitters in this house that can handle 3 devices, so I go into one splitter which feeds one TIVO and then feeds a second splitter that feeds the modem and the third TIVO.  This third TIVO is the one that is experiencing degradation in quality.  If I leave one of the TIVO's disconnected and just run the modem and one TIVO through ONE splitter....everything appears to be good.

I am sure that there is a better way to split the service in the guest house (Starting with a simple splitter that has 3 outputs).  However, wondering if I should have a powered amplified comscope in this guest house vs the basic splitters.  If I should not have a second amplified splitter, is there a particular kind of splitter that I should have since the signal is coming from an amplified splitter 270ft away?

Comment: I do not know enough to answer, but know that each splitter will reduce the signal some, that plus the 270ft does not help.  The grade of coax will matter also.

Comment: If you're running #6 coax you're limited to about 150-160 feet if your terminations are good and so forth. #11 coax should do it (about 300')...provided everything is in good repair.

Comment: You can purchase splitters with a built-in amplifier. Search for `CATV distribution amplifier`. I have seen everything from two outlets to sixty-four outlets. Purchase one that is compatible with your CATV service (your want the same frequencies supported). Your second problem might be running cable 270 feet. Low quality cable, poor connectors, etc. can limit usable length. To know if you cable is the problem, you would need test equipment. In the worst case a good distribution amplifier will improve everything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply that you have too many devices.

Each splitter *halves* the signal strength (cuts it by 3dB), as the power is diverted to two devices.

You basically prove this yourself:

> This third TIVO is the one that is experiencing degregation in quality. If I leave one of the TIVO's disconnected and just run the modem and one TIVO through ONE splitter....everything appears to be good.

You need to add more power to the system, or reduce consumption (e.g. fewer splitters). You need an amplifier, or you have to go with fewer devices.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of easy low-cost options:

1. Ask the cable company to fix this.  They usually don't charge a huge amount, if anything, for running and repairing cables, splitters, etc.   They have equipment that can detect where problems exist so they can pinpoint and repair them.

OR

2. Do some easy things yourself to eliminate the source of most common problems:

- Check all the cables, especially the outdoor one, for signs of damage.  The outdoor one needs to be intact and not admit water into the outer jacket.  If it's cracked or damaged you have to replace it.
- Learn how to terminate cables.  Look to see if all the terminations are well done and in good shape.  If not, cut them off and re-do them.   It's easy, you need a $20 tool and half an hour of practice on a scrap piece of coax with youtube to teach you.
- Make sure the amp is properly plugged in and powered up.  I know this sounds obvious but go do it.
- Make sure all the connections are screwed down properly.  Use a wrench.  These are harder to tighten than they should be.
- Replace the cascaded splitters with one high quality multi-port one.  I don't know if you can cascade amps?  Never tried it, but it shouldn't be necessary.  IF the first amp is delivering a decent signal to the guest house, a three-way split should be fine.

OR

3. Oh come on, why do you need cable in a guest house?  Buy a good pair of wifi mesh routers, mount them on the outside walls of both buildings, eliminate ALL the cabling, get Smart TV and a couple of streaming subscriptions, and your guests better not complain.  :)

Comment: The problem isn't that it's low quality splitters. The problem is simply that a splitter - because of physics - reduces available signal by 50%, or -3dB, because they split it two ways. He confirms this when he writes that it works fine when one device is removed. He has too many splitters and have to add power.